# stacks/packages Turtlebot explores floor and maps autonomously?

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, stack, gmapping-demo, slam-gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, ROS ANSWERS community!
I'm looking for stacks or packages for Turtlebot that will have it autonomously navigate a single floor of a building and create a 2D map of it, probably working in conjunction with the gmapping_demo or similar program. I want to have the robot be able to do the mapping all on its own without the need for a teleop.
If anyone has knowledge of any such stacks or packages here on ROS, I would appreciate the help in finding them. Thank you in advance, and have a wonderful day!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40431/stacks/packages-turtlebot-explores-floor-and-maps-autonomously?/) by [Sardonyx](https://answers.ros.org/users/2607/sardonyx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-08-02

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your message is quite old, but I will answer it anyway. Look up the Explore package which implements frontier based exploration. You can use it with SLAM to have your robot build a map autonomously.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/explore

I also modified the package to use it with a real turtlebot, but it doesn't work perfectly. https://github.com/LadyZayin/explore

---

Originally posted by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) with karma: 343 on 2013-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-06-10**:
I'll upvote this, if you add a link to the ROS wiki or code. :-)

**Comment by [Zayin](https://answers.ros.org/users/4858/zayin/) on 2013-06-11**:
Alright lol! Yeah, I was being lazy.